# Workflow Service vs WCF service that executes a single workflow

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

Trying to decide if I need to implement a WF service or just stick with a WCF service that simply invokes a workflow and returns the result.

I dont need correlation handles, or any need to pause the workflow somewhere in the middle of its execution.  It just merely needs to execute a workflow and return the result.  Also, I might want to add a few methods to the service that do not involve workflows at all.  So is there benefit one way or the other, or is a WF service just a pretty wrapper for exposing a workflow as a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you do not go for WF service if you don't need the bells and whistles. The WF Service really puts you into an enterprise-oriented use case straitjacket.  If that's not where you're going then go for a looser integration with WF.

My two cents.

Comment: Thanks.  That's more or less the conclusion I came to.  Im sure a WF-specific service fits a scenario somewhere, just not mine as explained above.